# Is it safe to use Apple's Private Framework UXKit for MacOS application development?

Tags: xcode, macos, uikit, appkit, osx-chameleon

While searching for an alternative of UIKit for MacOS, I came across UXKit (a private framework used by Apple to develop new [Photos app](https://9to5mac.com/2015/02/05/uxkit-framework/)). I found one demo app made with UXKit [here](https://github.com/insidegui/UXKitDemo) and another demo app [here](https://github.com/justMaku/UXKit-Headers-And-Sample). They include headers of UXKit, generated by class-dump. Both of the apps build and runs on MacOS (High Sierra 10.13.1) successfully.

The question is if we include these headers in an Xcode project and develop MacOS app, will it be safely published on Mac AppStore? If No, then is it okay to use UXKit in MacOS apps and publish them outside Mac AppStore.

Read more about UXKit [here](https://medium.com/@guilhermerambo/why-uikit-for-macos-is-important-ff4e74a82cf0).

I came across [Chameleon](https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon), but it looks like it is not maintained for a long and it is not using UXKit (it is trying to mimic UXKit), so I'm not interested in it.

Comment: Hmm Sounds interesting.Well i get to know that as it is private framework, Apple will not allow. However you can create mac app and use as testing mode and do not make it live.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not safe to use a system private framework in a shipping application. The framework could change in incompatible ways between OS versions, or even be removed completely.